# Silverlight - determine if the mouse is dragging

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Canvas with event handlers for MouseMove & MouseLeftButtonUp. Inside the canvas I have placed image icons. I want to rotate the icons using drag events like the iPhone. How can I capture the click event on an image?

Comment: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html  Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, MouseLeftButtondown event i am using for dragging then how i can get actual click event to enter inside menus?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  Specifically, what does "how i can get actual click event to enter inside menus?" mean?  I'm not familiar with iPhone functionality so possibly that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your try!! May be my explanation will clear above question i am tring build similar control on silverlight like iphone spining effect on mouse move or drag. I have taken canvas and image icons inside it. to recongnise movement I have captured canvas mouse events, now suppose i want to differentiate drap and actual click on icon. How i can differentiate events and how? to enter inside link after clicking on icon can anybody help me!!

Comment: Oh I see.  You don't want to drag the image, you want to rotate the image.  Now you want to determine, when you move the mouse, if you should be rotating the image or not?  If so, you need set a bool to record mousedown events and then clear the bool when mouseup happens.

Comment: Alternately, you could check e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed as in the example I linked.  See `List_MouseMove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if you are dragging either:

1. Record when a mousedown event is fired and then clear that record when mouseup fires.  Check this record in the mousemove event.
2. Check `e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed` in your mousemove event.

Comment: I think I can try this, will implement accept your answer thanks!!

Comment: I implemented the solution by appraoch you have provided with some more R&D.